# How do I run an if/else statement based on a local storage value-boolean type?

Tags: javascript, cordova, if-statement, local-storage

I want this code to find a local storage value and if it is true show a grid but if it is false, hide the grid. I tried this code but I can't get it to work right. Any ideas on what I did wrong?

```
var v = localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid'); 
if (v===true)
{
jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").show();
}
else jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").hide();
```

Comment: `localStorage` only returns `string`. You first need to convert the string value into an actual actual boolean.

Comment: Try this: `var v = (localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid')=='true')`.This checks if the value returned from localStorage equals 'true', and if so, sets `v` to TRUE, otherwise to FALSE.

Comment: What are the possible values of `localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid')` other than `null`?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles true and false are the only options.

Comment: To be exact, string 'true' and string 'false', are the only options. Right? (As you probably know, boolean false and string 'false' never equal. And boolean true and string 'true' are not identical.)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles No it is boolean true/false.

Comment: You may be feeding localStorage a boolean type, but currently it returns a string type. Test this yourself with a `console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid'))`.

Answer (score 2):

The getItem function of localStorage return string if you want your code to work consider change it to.

Here is a jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/dkabf953/1/

```
var v = localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid'); 
if (v== 'true') { // Check if it's equal to the string true
    jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").show();
} else {
    jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").hide();
}
```

Comment: So I have check boxes that determine how the local storage is set. If it is checked, it is true and if it isn't it is false so how would I get it to say if checked set value to true else false. @KhaledBentoumi

Comment: @EllenSchlechter just edited my code and added a jsFiddle example. Normally you don't have to change anything beside the code that you posted in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try `JSON.parse` it could be that the value stored is not a boolean and make sure you use `JSON.stringify` when you set the item.

```js
    // storing value using JSON.stringify
    localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(value));
    
    -------------------------------------------------------------

    // retrieving value using JSON.parse
    var v = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkcalfid')); 
    if (v===true)
    {
    jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").show();
    }
    else jQuery('[name="mobilegridcell_385"]').closest("tr").hide();
```